# What is a good practice to encapsulate multiple JavaScript files within 1 ES6 module?

Tags: javascript, es6-modules

Having a C# / C++ packaging structure in mind, how do I achieve to have JS-classes in individual files all imported as a single name space?

My currently working solution is to use an additional "package"-script file, which then encapsulates all classes. See the code below.

It seems as this includes a lot of overhead (updating the package-script-exports with every new class, importing this script in every new class).

ClassA.js:

```
import * as MyPackage from "../MyPackage.js";

export default class ClassA {/* some Class Code */}

export {
    ClassA
};
```

MyPackage.js:

```
import ClassA from "./module/ClassA.js";
import ClassB from "./module/ClassB.js";

export {
   ClassA,ClassB
}
```

script.js:

```
import * as MyPackage from "./MyPackage.js"

let a = new MyPackage.ClassA();
```

What would be a best practice for that?

Comment: Many good questions generate some degree of opinion based on expert experience, but answers to this question will tend to be almost entirely based on opinions, rather than facts, references, or specific expertise. https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> My currently working solution is to use an additional "package"-script file, which then encapsulates all classes.

Yes, this is the best practice. The "package" script file is typically called `index.js` placed in the directory of the package, as that's what the folder path is resolved to when importing.

> importing this script in every new class

No, you should not do that. It introduces a circular dependency. As long as your module doesn't depend on any of the other classes, it should not import anything. There is no "package declaration", the module is a standalone file with its own dependencies.

Notice also that you shouldn't export your class twice from the module, the default export is enough. So you'd use

```
// mypackage/classA.js:

export default class ClassA {
    /* some Class Code */
}
```

```
// mypackage/index.js:

export { default as ClassA } from "./classA.js";
export { default as ClassB } from "./classB.js";
// your solution of importing, then exporting works as well.
```

```
// script.js:

import * as MyPackage from "./mypackage";
const a = new MyPackage.ClassA();

// or

import { ClassA } from "./mypackage";
const a = new ClassA();
```

Comment: Thank you very much. That makes sense.

Comment: Using other classes of the same package within the package would still require an individual import, I quess? But then I probably would not need the package/namespace as the overall encapsulation would still apply (preventing any name collision for example)?

Comment: Yes, if you're using other classes then you'd need to import them - individually is the easiest. Name collisions are prevented by the unambiguous paths - `import … from './classB.js';` imports the package's `ClassB`.